# How to create a BSON document with nested expandoObjects, one being a converted Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, bson

I have an expandoObject d , and I want to to iterate through a dictionary and take its keys and values to make a new object, {key:value, key:value} and then assign that new object to d and of course finally serialize it as a bsonDocument for insertion.

if simply take the dictionary and do a .toArray(), i get no mongoDB serialization errors, but if I create a new expandObject out of that new object, or simply pass the dictionary i mentioned as d.newObject  I get a non helpful mondodb serialization error.

How would I go about this (1), and what am I missing about what a BSON document expects as far what can and cannot be serialized?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing this kind of dynamic type functionality for MongoDB with `ExpandoObject` from scratch yourself you could profit from using a dynamic ORM or ODM like [Slazure](http://www.slazure.com/) for this, MongoDB support is still in closed beta but should be publically available soon. Here is an example where a Slazure Linq query returns some documents from the "TestCustomers" collection and where each documents property name is written to the console:

```
using SysSurge.Slazure.MongoDB.Linq;
using SysSurge.Slazure.Core;
using SysSurge.Slazure.Core.Linq.QueryParser;

public void EnumProperties()
{
    // Get a reference to the collection
    dynamic storage = new QueryableStorage<DynDocument>("mongodb://user:pass@example.org/MongoDBExample");
    QueryableCollection<DynDocument> collection = storage.TestCustomers;

    // Build collection query
    var queryResult = collection.Where("SignedUpForNewsletter = true and Age < 22");

    foreach (DynDocument document in queryResult)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IDynProperty> keyValuePair in document)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to get actual the `BsonDocument` object then you can use get it from the Slazure `DynDocument` object by calling the `Document` method, example follows:

```
foreach (DynDocument document in queryResult)
{
    BsonDocument bsonDoc = document.Document    
    Console.WriteLine(bsonDoc["someProperty"].AsString());
```